# Javascript function will not activate onClick

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

In my page head:

```
<script>
function formula()
{
    document.forms["inquire"]["search"].value.scrollIntoView();
}
</script>
```

In my page body:

```
<div id="nav">
<form id="inquire" name="inquire" onSubmit="return false;">
Search or inquire here: <input type="text" id="search" name="search" value="<?php search($_GET['search']) ?>" autocomplete="off"/>
<input type="button" name="btnSearch" id="btnSearch" onClick="formula();"/>
</form>
</div>
```

What I want to happen here is that, when *btnSearch* is clicked, it activates *formula()*, taking the value from *search* in form *inquire*, and then scrolling to the value in a separate div I have called *formula*. This works if I put **document.getElementById(this.form.search.value).scrollIntoView();** directly into the *onClick* for *btnSearch*, however it refuses to work no matter how I set it up as a function. Does anyone here know why it might be doing this, or how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because your function is erroneous:

```
function formula() {
  document.getElementById(document.forms.inquire.search.value).scrollIntoView();
}
```

That code gets the value of the search field and uses it for an "id" lookup. It'd probably be a good idea to check that there actually is an "id" with the value typed in:

```
function formula() {
  var element = document.getElementById(document.forms.inquire.search.value);

  if (element) element.scrollIntoView();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Pointy! I used what you said at the beginning and it works exactly as I need it now. Thank you!