# Javascript: function does not activate onClick

Tags: javascript, html

New on JS.

I'm following a tutorial.

I've a function that ask for your name and prints:

"Hi ("name"), today is: "actual date"".

My function works great if just put in the js file.

But going beyond the tutorial, when experimenting with "onclick" on a button, the functions is not lunched.

So far:

1.- The functions is well structurated.
2.- HTML onclick lunches any "alert();" message, but the one calling my function. Just a prompt asking for your name is lunched.

I've searched Google and here.

[Javascript function will not activate onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619627/javascript-function-will-not-activate-onclick])[1](http://jsfiddle.net/OmarGon/mxe6ke1j/) (but this is not my case, since my function do work).

JSFIDDLE:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/OmarGon/mxe6ke1j/)

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<section>     
     <button onclick="alert(messageParts.join(''));">Click to enter your name!</button>
</section>
```

JS:

```
function getMonthName(index) {
var months = ["January", "February", "March",
             "April", "May", "June", "July", "August",
             "September", "October", "November", "December"];

return months[index];

}



function abbrName(text) {
    return text.substr(0,3);
}



var date = new Date();


var messageParts = [
    "Hello, ",
    prompt("Please, enter your name","Please, enter your name"),
    ". Today is ",
    date.getDate(),
    " ",
    abbrName(getMonthName(date.getMonth())),
    " ",
    ", ",
    date.getFullYear()

];
```

**UPDATE 1:**

1.- I think i have to use 'comillas simples' when calling a functions with "" in the outside. Now my function works, but not 100% as wished:

1.1.- The prompt is launched when page loads, when it should be launched when clicking the button.

1.2.-You have to enter a name when the prompt is launched, because it's not launched anymore.

Comment: You are mixing quotes all the time, when you use `"`, you cant use `"` once more inside - you need to change it to  `'` example: you cant use `"Hi ("name")"`, you should use `"Hi ('name')"`

Comment: Please load the javascript before the html is loaded like this https://jsfiddle.net/OmarGon/mxe6ke1j/

Comment: @areim, i just realized that. thanks. see update 1.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you're advised not to use the inline `onclick` attribute for attaching events to your elements. Instead, use an `eventListener` to handle the event

```
//This works when your button is first in the DOM tree
var button = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert(messageParts.join(""));
});
```

**EDIT**

This is javascript so it will go in the file with the .js extension. If I were you, I would add an id attribute to your button, and of course remove the onclick attribute, like so:

```
<button id="click">Click to enter your name!</button>
```

And then instead of my previous code, use a querySelector, like so:

```
var button = document.querySelector("#click");
button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert(messageParts.join(""));
});
```

Comment: yes the button is first in the DOM. This code goes in the "js" file, right? 

How should i change the HTML (do i have to?)?  I need the prompt to be launched when click the button not when loading the page. thanks.

Comment: @OmarGonzales see my EDIT

Answer (score 2):

`messageParts` is a variable that you declare in the scope of your `onload` function (the function is not visible in you question because you defined it in your JSFiddle configuration):

[image: Onload]

Your onclick attribute can only access *global* variables, which `messageParts` is not.

Don't use `on...` attributes. Bind your event handlers with JavaScript instead (e.g. the `addEventListener` method).

```js
function getMonthName(index) {
  var months = ["January", "February", "March",
    "April", "May", "June", "July", "August",
    "September", "October", "November", "December"
  ];
  return months[index];
}


function abbrName(text) {
  return text.substr(0, 3);
}

var date = new Date();

var messageParts = [
  "Hello, ",
  prompt("Please, enter your name", "Please, enter your name"),
  ". Today is ",
  date.getDate(),
  " ",
  abbrName(getMonthName(date.getMonth())),
  " ",
  ", ",
  date.getFullYear()
];

function clickHandler(event) {
  alert(messageParts.join(""));
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
```

```html
<article>
  <h1>Función User's name and date</h1>
  <p>Nombre y fecha del día</p>
  <section>
    <button type="button">Click to enter your name !</button>
  </section>
</article>
```

Comment: i see the code works on jsfiddle. But not in my local preview. Should i add something, somewhere? What should i look for? *the prompt lunches, but clicking on "button" has not effect.

Comment: @OmarGonzales — I explained what you have to do in this answer. I even gave a complete code example.

Answer (score 0):

`onclick="alert(messageParts.join(""));"` onclick wasn't getting the message part, so in `onclick` I have just called a function which is doing the same job as desired.

```js
function joinMsg() {
  function getMonthName(index) {
    var months = ["January", "February", "March",
      "April", "May", "June", "July", "August",
      "September", "October", "November", "December"
    ];

    return months[index];

  }



  function abbrName(text) {
    return text.substr(0, 3);
  }



  var date = new Date();


  var messageParts = [
    "Hello, ",
    prompt("Please, enter your name", "Please, enter your name"),
    ". Today is ",
    date.getDate(),
    " ",
    abbrName(getMonthName(date.getMonth())),
    " ",
    ", ",
    date.getFullYear()

  ];
  alert(messageParts.join(""));
}
```

```html
<section>
  <button onclick="joinMsg();">Click to enter your name!</button>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks noise. Tried this, is good. But the prompt for your name should be load just when clicking the button. With my code, and this code, it loads when the page is openened.